# Debian - Firefox is Very Slow, Chromium is Very Fast

Tags: linux, firefox, debian, chromium

- I'm working on a fresh install of Debian Wheezy, running Firefox 28.0 64-bit (although I've also tried 17.0). FF does not have any plugins installed, and all about:config is set to default.
- Firefox is terribly slow (taking 30+ seconds to load yahoo.com). Running FF28 on my Windows machine works fine
- Chromium loads yahoo.com in the blink of an eye
- **FF also takes longer to load local files**. The page loads very quickly, but then the "loading wheel" continues to spin, whereas Chromium finishes loading the same html file in an instant.

> Different attempts I've made:
>
> - Changing the pipelining settings that are recommended on the net
> - Disabling ipv6 in FF and GRUB
> - Setting "gfx.xrender.enabled" to False and "layers.acceleration.force-enabled" to True
> - At first I thought it might have something to do with DNS or caching, but if I re-visit a webpage it will load the visible content much faster, but the "loading wheel" will continue to spin for a long time.
> - Disabling javascript - things are just as slow.

My main reason for not just switching to Chromium is that I have many selenium tests that make use of about:config, and I would have to rewrite all of these settings for Chromium. I'm foregoing IceWeasel due to add-on incompatibility.

EDIT:

Using FF's Web Developer Network Timings I've deduced that it's something with the DNS.

- Linux takes 2129ms to resolve yahoo.com
- Windows takes 0ms to resolve
- all other timings are faster in Linux

> The only difference between my Windows and Debian systems is that Windows is using the gateway for DNS resolution and Linux is using defined, external DNS servers.  However, if I try to set the gateway as DNS under Linux it fails to resolve any addresses.

Any idea how to resolve --pun intended-- this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've changed my DNS settings to 8.8.8.8 (Google), and FF is now finally loading quickly. Is this considered good practice? How would I configure my DNS without using Google's server?

Comment: No, its not good practice handing all that data (and power) to Google.

Answer (score -1):

OpenDNS

```
208.67.222.222
208.67.220.220
```

or OpenDNS for children safe-browsing

```
208.67.222.123
208.67.220.123
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.